# error C7011: implicit cast from "vec4" to "vec3"

Tags: glsl

I have looked as best as I can, and no one is having that error with the same basic code as I have.

Someone please look at the code below and let me know what I need to fix please and thank you:

gl_Position = vec4(0.25 * position, 1.0);

I know its kind of a newb thing as I am currently learning GLSL, so the help would be very appreciated.

Edit: If I read other peoples similar errors correctly, its in my fragment file, not the vertex. The below code might be more helpful in figuring this out.

```
#version 430

out vec3 fragColor;

void main()
{
 fragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What type is `position` of?

Comment: if you would like I could just paste the whole code

Comment: Looks like the error message is self-explantory: you've declared your output `fragColor` as a `vec3` and you're trying to assign a `vec4` to it....

Comment: I figured it out i think haha

Answer (score 3):

I guess the "position" variable is declared as vec4, but the constructor expects a vec3 expression, since you are passing fourth element as a scalar 1.0.

Try
gl_Position = vec4(0.25 * position.xyz, 1.0);

Comment: still got the same error even with the xyz as notepad++ apparently doesnt recognize it...maybe the GLSL lib I added to it is out of date. sigh....this is gonna be a struggle lol

Comment: if i read the error right, its in my fragment file, not my vertex.

Answer (score 0):

you declared fragColor as vec3 ,change that to vec4 and try run the code ,i got the same error when i done something like this
out vec4 fragColor;